# When solving Logarithmic Inequalities why are the two following methods not the same?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

When solving $\log_6 \left(\frac{12x-1}{x-3}\right)<0$, I would raise both sides as exponents to a base of $6$, resulting in $\frac{12x-1}{x-3}<1$, then move the $1$ to the left side, make a common denominator resulting in $\frac{11x+2}{x-3}<0$, and use a number line graph to solve, finding the answer as $x\in (-2/11, 3)$, restricted by the domain resulting in the final answer as $x\in(-2/11, 1/12)$.

But I have seen it solved by using a property of logs and separating $\log_6 \left(\frac{12x-1}{x-3}\right)<0$ into $\log_6 (12x-1)-\log6 (x-3)<0$, then moving $\log_6 (x-3)$ to the right side of the inequality resulting in $\log_6 (12x-1)<\log_6 (x-3)$, and then dropping the logs to make $12x-1<x-3$.

When I look at this graphically I know the second way of solving is not correct, but I am trying to figure out why?

Answer (score 1):

The argument of the logarithmic must be greater than zero.  So, we must have

$$\frac{12x-1}{x-3}>0$$

This implies that either $x>3$ or $x<1/12$.  So, with $x$ in this domain we have

$$\frac{12x-1}{x-3}<1$$

If $x>3$, then $12x-1<x-3\implies x<-2/11$, which is extraneous.  But this (i.e., $x>3$), is tacitly assumed in the second methodology.

If $x<1/12$, then

$$12x-1>x-3\implies x>-2/11$$

The admissible solution is therefore $x\in(-2/11,1/12)$